# python,numpy matrix must be 2-dimensional

Tags: numpy

Why the line3 raise valueError‘ matrix must be 2-dimensional’

```
import numpy as np
np.mat([[[1],[2]],[[10],[1,3]]])
np.mat([[[1],[2]],[[10],[1]]])
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't use the `matrix` API. See: [Deprecation status of the NumPy matrix class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53254738/deprecation-status-of-the-numpy-matrix-class)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this code raises an error is because NumPy tries to determine the dimensionality of your input using nesting levels (nesting levels -> dimensions).
If, at some level, some elements do not have the same length (i.e. they are incompatible), it will create the array using the *deepest* nesting it can, using the objects as the elements of the array.

For this reason:

```
np.mat([[[1],[2]],[[10],[1,3]]])
```

Will give you a matrix of objects (lists), while:

```
np.mat([[[1],[2]],[[10],[1]]])
```

would result in a 3D array of numbers which `np.mat()` does not want to squeeze into a matrix.

Also, please avoid using `np.mat()` in your code as it is deprecated.
Use `np.array()` instead.

Incidentally, `np.array()` would work in both cases and it would give you a `(2, 2, 1)`-shaped array of `int`, which you could `np.squeeze()` into a matrix if you like.
However, it would be better to start from nesting level of 2 if all you want is a matrix:

```
np.array([[1, 2], [10, 1]])
```

Comment: No problem. If this solves your problem, perhaps you could upvote / mark it as solution.